# JSTL - Comparing Strings

Tags: java, string, jsp, jstl, equals

I'm trying to compare two strings but I can't get the result I need

I tried these formats:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${company == multi }">
       <a href="dashResumo.jsp?tr=<%=tr%>&company=VVO&nm=<%=nmTorr%>"></a>
       <a href="dashResumo.jsp?tr=<%=tr%>&company=GPA&nm=%=nmTorr%></a>                                    
   </c:when>
 </c:choose>

<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${company == 'multi' }">
       <a href="dashResumo.jsp?tr=<%=tr%>&company=VVO&nm=<%=nmTorr%>"></a>
       <a href="dashResumo.jsp?tr=<%=tr%>&company=GPA&nm=%=nmTorr%>">GPA</a>                                    
   </c:when>
</c:choose>

<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${company.equals("multi") }">
       <a href="dashResumo.jsp?tr=<%=tr%>&company=VVO&nm=<%=nmTorr%></a>
       <a href="dashResumo.jsp?tr=<%=tr%>&company=GPA&nm=%=nmTorr%></a>                                    
   </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

but none of these formats worked for me.

Using JSTL-1.2 library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${company eq 'multi'}">
        <a href="dashResumo.jsp?tr=<%=tr%>&company=VVO&nm=<%=nmTorr%>">VVO</a>
        <a href="dashResumo.jsp?tr=<%=tr%>&company=GPA&nm=<%=nmTorr%>">GPA</a>                                    
    </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: @ThiagoVacare can you post the error and full code please?

Comment: there's no error but debugging I can see the that the variable company is bringing the right value "multi" but when I compare both variables it returns  false

Comment: this is how I'm getting the parameter:

String company = ((request.getParameter("company") == null)?
         ("GPA"):(request.getParameter("company")));

Comment: O posted the wrong code. This is the one:
String company = ((request.getParameter("company") == null)?
         ("multi"):(request.getParameter("company")));

Comment: @ThiagoVacare `"multi"`is a literal, and `company = company.toLowerCase().trim();` ??

Comment: "multi" is literal and company receives "multi" from the parameters. I printed company and it shows multi.

Comment: @ThiagoVacare could you try with. `<c:when test="${'multi' eq 'multi'}">` to limit the problem?

Comment: `<c:when test="${'multi' eq 'multi'}">` returns true

Comment: @ThiagoVacare  try now: `<c:when test="${param.company eq 'multi'}">`

Comment: It sort of worked. For some reason when I use `${company }` it returns blank. I guess I can use `${param.company }` instead. Thanks a lot